# MS SQL query to return next start time and pervious end time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sql-server-2012

I have a table with columns, Machine, job_name, Start_time.  Machine and job name are text and Start_time is Date/time.

I would like a query that will return the next chronological start time for a machine as the end time.

I have tried to use a MIN(start_time) > Start time.  But this returns a row of Multiple start times for every possible end time.  I am not sure how to identify the Start_time per row as the comparision start_time.

Table example.

```
MAchine, Job_name, Start_time


scanner, A1A, 1/24/2014 8:00am

scanner, ABA, 1/24/2014 12:00pm

scanner, A1B, 1/24/2014 10:00pm

scanner, AC3, 1/25/2014 4:00am

scanner, AG2, 1/25/2014 11:00am

scanner, BK4, 1/25/2014 3:00pm

scanner1, AA, 1/24/2014 9:00am

scanner1, AA, 1/24/2014 1:00pm

scanner1, AB, 1/24/2014 8:00pm

scanner1, A3, 1/25/2014 2:00am

scanner1, A2, 1/25/2014 7:00am

scanner1, B4, 1/25/2014 2:00pm

scanner2, A1, 1/24/2014 11:00am

scanner2, AB, 1/24/2014 12:00pm

scanner2, A1, 1/24/2014 5:00pm

scanner2, AC, 1/25/2014 1:00am

scanner2, A2, 1/25/2014 5:00am

scanner2, K4, 1/25/2014 2:00pm
```

I would like results below.

```
MAchine, Job_name, Start_time

scanner, A1A, 1/24/2014 8:00am, 1/24/2014 12:00pm

scanner, ABA, 1/24/2014 12:00pm, 1/24/2014 10:00pm

scanner, A1B, 1/24/2014 10:00pm, 1/25/2014 4:00am

scanner, AC3, 1/25/2014 4:00am, 1/25/2014 11:00am

scanner, AG2, 1/25/2014 11:00am, 1/25/201 3:00pm

scanner, BK4, 1/25/2014 3:00pm, 

scanner1, AA, 1/24/2014 9:00am, 1/24/2014 1:00pm

scanner1, AA, 1/24/2014 1:00pm, 1/24/2014 8:00pm

scanner1, AB, 1/24/2014 8:00pm, 1/25/2014 2:00am

scanner1, A3, 1/25/2014 2:00am, 1/25/2014 7:00am

scanner1, A2, 1/25/2014 7:00am, 1/25/2014 2:00pm

scanner1, B4, 1/25/2014 2:00pm, 

scanner2, A1, 1/24/2014 11:00am, 1/24/2014 12:00pm

scanner2, AB, 1/24/2014 12:00pm, 1/24/2014 5:00pm

scanner2, A1, 1/24/2014 5:00pm, 1/25/2014 1:00am

scanner2, AC, 1/25/2014 1:00am, 1/25/2014 5:00am

scanner2, A2, 1/25/2014 5:00am, 1/25/2014 2:00pm

scanner2, K4, 1/25/2014 2:00pm,
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running on and what is the compatibility mode?

Comment: Sql Server 2012.  Compatibility leve 100.

Comment: `LAG` and `LEAD` still work at 2008 compatibility level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will work with most databases:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f14f5/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([MAchine] varchar(8), [Job_name] varchar(3), [Start_time] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([MAchine], [Job_name], [Start_time])
VALUES
    ('scanner', 'A1A', '1/24/2014 8:00am'),
    ('scanner', 'ABA', '1/24/2014 12:00pm'),
    ('scanner', 'A1B', '1/24/2014 10:00pm'),
    ('scanner', 'AC3', '1/25/2014 4:00am'),
    ('scanner', 'AG2', '1/25/2014 11:00am'),
    ('scanner', 'BK4', '1/25/2014 3:00pm'),
    ('scanner1', 'AA', '1/24/2014 9:00am'),
    ('scanner1', 'AA', '1/24/2014 1:00pm'),
    ('scanner1', 'AB', '1/24/2014 8:00pm'),
    ('scanner1', 'A3', '1/25/2014 2:00am'),
    ('scanner1', 'A2', '1/25/2014 7:00am'),
    ('scanner1', 'B4', '1/25/2014 2:00pm'),
    ('scanner2', 'A1', '1/24/2014 11:00am'),
    ('scanner2', 'AB', '1/24/2014 12:00pm'),
    ('scanner2', 'A1', '1/24/2014 5:00pm'),
    ('scanner2', 'AC', '1/25/2014 1:00am'),
    ('scanner2', 'A2', '1/25/2014 5:00am'),
    ('scanner2', 'K4', '1/25/2014 2:00pm')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t3.MAchine, t3.Job_name, t3.Start_time, tm.MinNextTime
from Table1 t3
left outer join (
 select t1.MAchine, t1.Start_time, min(t2.Start_time) as MinNextTime
 from Table1 t1
 inner join Table1 t2 on t1.MAchine = t2.MAchine and t2.Start_time > t1.Start_time
 group by t1.MAchine, t1.Start_time
) tm on t3.MAchine = tm.MAchine and t3.Start_time = tm.Start_time
order by t3.MAchine, t3.Start_time
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f14f5/4/0)**:

```
|  MACHINE | JOB_NAME |                     START_TIME |                    MINNEXTTIME |
|----------|----------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|  scanner |      A1A | January, 24 2014 08:00:00+0000 | January, 24 2014 12:00:00+0000 |
|  scanner |      ABA | January, 24 2014 12:00:00+0000 | January, 24 2014 22:00:00+0000 |
|  scanner |      A1B | January, 24 2014 22:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 04:00:00+0000 |
|  scanner |      AC3 | January, 25 2014 04:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 11:00:00+0000 |
|  scanner |      AG2 | January, 25 2014 11:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 15:00:00+0000 |
|  scanner |      BK4 | January, 25 2014 15:00:00+0000 |                         (null) |
| scanner1 |       AA | January, 24 2014 09:00:00+0000 | January, 24 2014 13:00:00+0000 |
| scanner1 |       AA | January, 24 2014 13:00:00+0000 | January, 24 2014 20:00:00+0000 |
| scanner1 |       AB | January, 24 2014 20:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 02:00:00+0000 |
| scanner1 |       A3 | January, 25 2014 02:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 07:00:00+0000 |
| scanner1 |       A2 | January, 25 2014 07:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 14:00:00+0000 |
| scanner1 |       B4 | January, 25 2014 14:00:00+0000 |                         (null) |
| scanner2 |       A1 | January, 24 2014 11:00:00+0000 | January, 24 2014 12:00:00+0000 |
| scanner2 |       AB | January, 24 2014 12:00:00+0000 | January, 24 2014 17:00:00+0000 |
| scanner2 |       A1 | January, 24 2014 17:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 01:00:00+0000 |
| scanner2 |       AC | January, 25 2014 01:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 05:00:00+0000 |
| scanner2 |       A2 | January, 25 2014 05:00:00+0000 | January, 25 2014 14:00:00+0000 |
| scanner2 |       K4 | January, 25 2014 14:00:00+0000 |                         (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to consider looking at the [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and [LEAD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) functions available in SQL Server 2012 and above.

Comment: LAG and LEAD were added in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: ACK!  Thanks for that!  There was a reason I asked that.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: A quick google found some solutions talking about that.  This article seems like a good "lead" http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

Comment: Thank you.  Lag lead is a great hint for researching options.